# Comma operator precedence while used with ? : operator

Tags: c++, c, operator-precedence, comma-operator

I have no idea why the result of the two sub programs below are different:

```
    int a , b;

    a = 13, b=12;
    (a > b)? (a++,b--):(a--,b++); // Now a is 14 and b is 11

    a = 13, b=12;
    (a > b)? a++,b-- : a--,b++;   // Now a is 14 but b is 12
```

However for these cases, the results are identical:

```
    a = 13, b=12;
    (a < b) ? a++,b-- : a--,b++; // Now a is 12 and b is 13

    a = 13, b=12;
    (a < b) ? (a++,b--) : (a--,b++); // Again a is 12 and b is 13
```

Why parentheses make difference for the statement after `"?"`, but make no difference for the statement after `":"`? Do you have any idea?

Comment: One more reason not to use the comma in this way.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This one:

```
(a > b)? a++,b-- : a--,b++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
((a > b) ? (a++, b--) : a--), b++;
```

so `b` is always incremented and only sometimes decremented.  There is no way to parse the comma operator between `?` and `:` other than as parenthesized in the 'equivalent to' expression.  But after the `:`, the unparenthesized comma terminates the ternary `?:` operator and leaves the increment as unconditionally executed.  The precedence of the comma operator is very, very low.

Answer (score 4):

The relevant parts of the C++ grammar are:

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-or-expression
    logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

```
assignment-expression:
    conditional-expression
    logical-or-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
    throw-expression
```

```
expression:
    assignment-expression
    expression, assignment-expression
```

In summary, while the 'middle' of a conditional expression can be a full expression extending up to the `:`, the last sub-expression can only be an *assignment-expression* which excludes expressions using the comma operator (other than where the comma operator appears as part of valid sub-expression of an *assignment-expression* such as a parenthesized *primary-expression* or as the second operand of another *conditional-expression*).

In C, the last sub-expression is more restricted, it cannot even be an assignment-expression although this is not a concern in your example.

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-OR-expression
    logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

Comment: This has to come from the C++ standard since 'throw-expression' is not a part of C.  However, the question is dual-tagged, so it is valid.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, it does. There are important differences between the C and C++ conditional operator grammars; I was browsing C++ questions and didn't notice the C tag.

Answer (score 3):

In this case

```
(a > b)? a++,b-- : a--,b++;
```

It is equivalent to

```
((a > b)? a++,b-- : a--),b++;
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's because `x ? y` cannot be considered a valid expression, therefore the comma can't split the operator there. `x ? y : z` is a valid expression, the the comma after the colon can split into two expressions.